# replace variable value on ruby template via puppet

Tags: puppet, erb

I am looking the way to have the result of this ruby template file:

```
ServerName 1.server.foo
```

knowing that if I run

```
$ facter -p fqdn
1.server.foo.internet.com
```

I would probably play with `<%= @fqdn %>` and .gsub?

```
server-id: <%= @fqdn %>.gsub(/.internet.com/, '')
```

Comment: oobs. seems not working well . 
`server-id: 01.server.foo.internet.com.gsub(/\.internet.comt/b/, '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire expression needs to be in the `<%= %>` tag, so try

```
server-id: <%= @fqdn.regsubst(/.internet.com/, '') %>
```

The template syntax is documented at https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_template_erb.html with examples of expressions used in `<%= %>` tags.

I'd also note that ERB templates have been replaced by [native Embedded Puppet EPP templates](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_template_epp.html), so it may be better to convert now.

Comment: am trying with EPP. 
   `server-id: <%= $facts[fqdn].gsub(/.internet.com/, '') %>;`
but, he do not like. Unknown function: 'gsub'

Answer (score 0):

using EPP with regsubst it works!

```
server-id: <%= $facts[fqdn].regsubst(/.internet.com/, '') %>
```

Comment: I've shamelessly updated my answer to use this, the correct function!